# Why is the response from my Web API not formed properly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a very basic Web API example that I constructed using the [example code from this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api):

## Code

#### Relevant Web.config Section

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

#### Route Configuration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

#### View Model

```
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### ApiController

```
public class SurveysController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Survey> All()
    {
        using (ITSurveyEntities model = new ITSurveyEntities())
        {
            return new List<Survey>(
                from s in model.Surveys
                select new Survey
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Description = s.Description,
                });
        }
    }
}
```

and it's leveraging `ITSurveyEntities`, which was a generated ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the database, which only contains a single table right now, `Survey`.

In short, I don't think I'm trying to do anything special here.

## Current Result

When I try and navigate to the API using something like `http://localhost:1681/api/surveys`, I get a response, but the file is named `surveys` with no extension. Further, if I try and `Save As` and give it say a `txt` extension, the download just fails.

## Expected Result

I would expect that the API would return a file names `surveys.json`, like the example project does with `products`, and the browser would ask me to open or save the file.

## What I've Tried

#### Comparing Web.config Files

I have compared the `Web.config` files between my project and the example code from the tutorial that works.

#### Comparing Routing

I have compared the routing configuration between my project and the example code from the tutorial that works.

#### Excluding WebDav

I've tried to exclude WebDav because my searches have indicated that it might be the cause. I did that by modifying the Web.config in a manner that matches [what's on this blog](http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2013/04/29/405-method-not-allowed-using-asp-net-web-api/).

### UPDATE 1

Okay, after the guidance by Joe Enos I found that the issue was that the view model was named `Survey` also and so it was throwing an error about ambiguity between the CLR type and the EDM type.

I resolved that by renaming the view model to `SurveyViewModel`, and the request to `http://localhost:1681/api/surveys` now returns a `HTTP 200` and downloads the file as expected.

Comment: Awesome write-up with your question. I don't have an answer, but I have to give you kudos for spelling it out in reasonable detail.

Comment: Maybe its about the default Fromatter. Did you remove the XMLFormatter to make JSON default? This annoying can cause some issues!

Comment: Try watching the raw request and response in Fiddler or your browser dev tools, and see what that looks like.

Comment: @JoeEnos, that lead me directly to my answer. Please see my edit, and add the debugging technique you gave me as the answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the raw request and response using Fiddler or your browser's dev tools, you should find some clues as to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The response type (xml, json, etc) will be dictated by the accepts header in your request. You didn't mention what browser you were using to call the service but I believe there is difference in the default accept header between browsers. If you only want to return only Json data from webapi try adding the following to the Global.Asax:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0,new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Media Formatters are essentially how the data from the Webapi method are serialized for the browser.